# Flex : arrayCollection in dataProvider

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I'm actually working on someone else code but I can't figure out something, I find the way the dataprovider is being accessed very peculiar in the mxml part.

extract 1 :

```
[Bindable] 
public var adrDataList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

[Bindable]
public var obj:Object = new Object();
```

extract 2 :

```
    adrDataList.getItemAt(0).id = null;
adrDataList.getItemAt(0).natureVoie = null;
adrDataList.getItemAt(0).numeroVoie = null;
adrDataList.getItemAt(0).nomVoie = null;
adrDataList.getItemAt(0).commune = null;
adrDataList.getItemAt(0).complementAdresse = null;
adrDataList.getItemAt(0).codePostal = null;
    obj.index = i;          
    obj.statutGeocodage = _model.service.getItemAt(i).statutGeocodage;
    obj.coordX = "484646868"
    obj.coordY = "455446846"                    
    adrDataList.addItemAt(obj, 0);
```

this is the mxml part:

```
<view:CustomDataGrid id="dgAdr" height="80" width="989" allowMultipleSelection="true"
    editable="{_model.isGeocodageActif}" 
    styleName="DataGrid" dataProvider="{adrDataList}" itemEditEnd="onEditItem(event)">
    <view:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="NumeroVoie" dataField="numeroVoie"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="NatureVoie" dataField="natureVoie"/>     
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="NomVoie" dataField="nomVoie"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Commune" dataField="commune"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="CodePostal" dataField="codePostal"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Géocod" editable="false">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:Text text="{(data.coordX == 0)? '' : data.coordX} - {(data.coordY == 0)? '' : data.coordY}" />
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>          
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Géocodage" editable="false"   dataField="statutGeocodage">
                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                        <mx:Component>
                            <formatter:geocodBtn color="{data.statutGeocodage}" horizontalAlign="center"
                                enabledBtns="{outerDocument._model.isGeocodageActif}"
                                click="outerDocument.onGeoClick(data.id, data.numeroVoie, data.natureVoie, data.nomVoie, data.commune, data.codePostal, data.idTechnicien, data.complementAdresse,event)">
                            </formatter:geocodBtn>
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>        
    </view:columns>
</view:CustomDataGrid>
```

What I don't get is why is data.coordX is working? shouldn't it be data.obj.coordX

Thanks

Ps : I'm using flex SDK 3.5

Comment: What you want to research is how a Flex `List` component uses an `ItemRenderer` to display the list elements. The `List` uses object pooling to so that it creates only as many `ItemRenderer` objects as necessary to display the list elements **that are currently visible**. When you scroll the list, it will re-use existing item renderers rather than creating new ones. To do this, the item renderer defines a `data` property. So in the context of the item renderer, the current element in the data provider can be referenced by this `data` property.

Comment: Note I referred to a `List` component above, but the same applies to the data grid components (the grids extend `List`). Also, I referred to an `ItemRenderer` class which exists in Flex 4, in Flex 3 many compoents implement an `IDataRenderer` interface (there was no formal ItemRenderer class).

Comment: Hi, you could use ItemRenderer component [link] https://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/08/datagrid_itemeditor_with_two_i.html). But first, to solve your problem, I would a Class for example "adrObject" that will have a getter function called g_coordX, something like this:

Comment: (continued here...) 
public function get g_coordX():Number{return internalObj.coordX;}
Remember that the class adrObject will have: id, natureVoie,numeroVoie,nomVoie,commune,complementAdresse,codePostal,internalObj, And internalObj will have: index ,statutGeocodage,coordX,coordY, And adrDataList will have adrObject type objects. Finally you must use getter inside the grid: <mx:Text text="{(data.g_coordX ....I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, if not understood, below I added a more complete example that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class:

```
    package
{
    public class AdrObject
    {
         public var id:Number;
         public var natureVoie:Number;
         public var numeroVoie:Number;
         public var nomVoie:Number;
         public var commune:Number;
         public var complementAdresse:String;
         public var codePostal:String;
         public var internalObj:Object; //or may be other, such as InternalAdrObject type

        public function AdrObject()
        {
        }

        public function get g_coordX():Number{
            return internalObj.coordX;
        }
    }
}
```

Mxml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            [Bindable] 
            [ArrayElementType("AdrObject")] 
            public var adrDataList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            [Bindable]
            public var obj:Object = new Object();

            public function init():void{
                var obj1:AdrObject = new AdrObject();
                var obj2:Object = new Object();
                obj1.id = null;
                obj1.natureVoie = null;
                obj1.numeroVoie = null;
                obj1.nomVoie = null;
                obj1.commune = null;
                obj1.complementAdresse = null;
                obj1.codePostal = null;
                obj2.index = 1;          
                obj2.statutGeocodage = 123;
                obj2.coordX = "484646868"
                obj2.coordY = "455446846"                    
                obj1.internalObj = obj2;
                adrDataList.addItem(obj1);
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:DataGrid id="grid" width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{adrDataList}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="g_coordX"/>       
        </mx:columns>   
    </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Now I get it, your second piece of code was very helpfull, thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the {data.coordX} parts? "obj" is the **data** that is binded to that property. Obj has it's own property "coordX" that is accessed with data.coordX

```
[Bindable]
public var obj:Object = new Object();
```

See [DataBinding on Flex3 help](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_2.html)

Comment: still not getting it, he is putting string in adrDataList then he is pûtting string in obj and then putting obj inside adrDataList.
Then adrDataList is renamed to data, am I wrong?